# If you install the Google Plugin for Eclipse, do you still need to download the App Engine Java SDK?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, eclipse-plugin

It's not clear to me if the Eclipse plugin completely replaces the need to download the SDK.

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the plugin includes the SDK. When you create a new App Engine project it automatically includes the SDK

Answer (score 1):

For the first time, I had to manually tell Eclipse where to look for the SDK even though I installed the SDK with the plugin through software update. Quite annoying.

Answer (score 1):

The Eclipse plugin automatically comes with the Google App Engine SDK. You dont need to download it separately. You need to use the sdk if you need to do any rollbacks using appcfg. For citing and example. The sdk in my system lies at

C:\eclipse\eclipse-jee-helios-win32\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.5.3.r36v201108301710\appengine-java-sdk-1.5.3